# How to update table with only new or changed values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my query but it makes lots of doubles and I need insert new and (maybe) update changed values.

```
INSERT INTO [FRIIB].[dbo].[ArchiveAnalog] 
                        (Date, ID, Value)
                        SELECT Date, ID, Value
                            FROM [LinkedOne].[FRIIB].[dbo].[ArchiveAnalog]
```

**My problem** is I need to compare not single value , I need to compare whole node with 3 values to check if there is existing ones.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert the missing values, following would do

```
INSERT INTO [FRIIB].[dbo].[ArchiveAnalog] (Date, ID, Value)
SELECT  laa.Date, laa.ID, laa.Value
FROM    [LinkedOne].[FRIIB].[dbo].[ArchiveAnalog] laa
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [FRIIB].[dbo].[ArchiveAnalog] aa ON aa.Date = laa.Date
                                                            AND aa.ID = laa.ID
                                                            AND aa.Value = laa.Value
WHERE   aa.ID IS NULL
```

To update existing values you might want to look into the [`MERGE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement

Answer (score 2):

Assuming SQL Server 2008 or above, use [`MERGE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) e.g.

```
MERGE INTO [FRIIB].[dbo].[ArchiveAnalog] 
USING (
       SELECT [Date], ID, [Value]
         FROM [LinkedOne].[FRIIB].[dbo].[ArchiveAnalog]
      ) AS source ([Date], ID, [Value])
   ON [Date] = source.[Date]
      AND ID = source.ID
      AND [Value] = source.[Value]
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT ([Date], ID, [Value])
      VALUES ([Date], ID, [Value]);
```